# Flush result set

Tags: sql-server, resultset

We have a stored procedure that returns 3 different result sets, and the first two take approx. 1 sec while the 3rd takes 20+ sec.

When running the SP in SSMS all 3 result sets are displayed at once after an initial delay of ~20 seconds.

Likewise when calling from .NET there is no delay between each call to `IDataReader#NextResult`, but there is a delay on the first call to `IDataReader#Read`.

If we modify the SP to stop after the first 2 result sets then the data is available immediately.

We want to start processing the results of the 1st 2 sets immediatly and not wait for all 3 result sets to be ready.

Is there a way to force SQL to flush the first 2 results sets so they can be consumed immediately?

Comment: yes, make the 1&2 result sets a parameter and the third another parameter. means you have to call it twice though. but solves your issue

Comment: `WAITFOR` maybe?

Comment: to be clear - we don't want SQL to deliberatly stop. We want it to send the results so they can be consumed and SQL should start working on the final resultset while the consumer is reading results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

..for ssms…

```
--resultsets after 5secs
select 1;
select 2;
waitfor delay '00:00:05'; -- simulate a long running query
select 3;
go
--two resultsets and the last after 5secs 
select 1;
select 2;
raiserror('', 0, 0) with nowait; -- flush results
waitfor delay '00:00:05';  -- simulate a long running query
select 3;
```